# Concentration bound for least-square approximation error via uniform row sampling

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, concentration-of-measure

While reading the following two papers:

1) Faster Least Squares Approximation of Drineas et al (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.1435.pdf)

2) Blendenpik: supercharging lapack's least-square solver of Avron et al (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.437.2874&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I've noticed that a classical inverse continuous least square problem 
\begin{align*}
Z = \min_x \Vert Ax - b \Vert_2^2
\end{align*}

can be approximated by using uniformly sampled rows (let's say $k$ rows) of $A$ to generate a matrix $\hat{A}$ and also uniformly sampling elements of vector $b$ to generate \hat{b}, in such a way that by taking:
\begin{align*}
x_R = arg\min_x \Vert \hat{A}x - \hat{b} \Vert_2^2
\end{align*}

for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have the following bound:
\begin{align*}
\Vert Ax_R - b \Vert_2^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)Z
\end{align*}
with probability 1-$\delta$ with $\delta = 0.2$.

I was trying to see if there is some general bound, since the authors only specifie the theorem for the case when $1-\delta = 0.8$.

What would be the algebraic expression for $\delta$ in this case, assuming $k$ as the number of rows to be sampled, with some given $\epsilon$?